# Symfony queryBuilder: too many queries

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I have an entity with a ManyToMany relationship with the User table:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *  name="offer_allowedusers",
 *  joinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *  },
 *  inverseJoinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *  }
 * )
 */
private $allowedUsers;
```

And, in the form, I want to display a dropdown (using *select2*) to select which users are allowed:

[image]

To do that, I made, in the Form building:

```
->add('allowedUsers', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
        },
        'label' => 'Allowed users',
        'required' => false,
        'multiple' => true
    ])
```

The problem is that it makes a query for each user, to get the username... So if I have 500 users, it makes 500 queries...

[image]

How can optimize and do a single query to fetch all the records?

Comment: Have you implemented the __toString() method in your User class ? this method would return the user name

Comment: I have, that returns `$this->username`. Without that it wouldn't display the usernames in the dropdown

Comment: Did you try to add `'choice_label' => 'username'` in the form builder options array?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov tried now, didn't work :(

Comment: Lookup how to create a custom dql query.  That will allows you to load the related users in one gulp.  And read up a bit on lazy loading vs eager loading.  Won't get very far with the orm unless you understand these key concepts.

Comment: Are you sure it's the User entity being queried 500 times? My guess is it's something the User-Entity has a relation to instead.

Comment: `[it makes a query for each user, to get the username]` shouldn't, the `EntityType` execute this query just one time, the `username` is retrieved for each iteration of the result. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/78a08f3a682eddb941ba806e0677b144fe28f4a2/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/EntityType.php#L32

Comment: @ccKep you're right, it's selecting all the fields from the user_profile and user_settings tables, which are OneToOne related to the users table.

Comment: ..even if I set them LAZY or EXTRA_LAZY `@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProfile", mappedBy="user", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")`

Comment: Doctrine *always* retrieves OneToOne relations no matter what.  You can't put a `LAZY` or `EXTRA_LAZY` setting to change that.  But, you can join them as well in your QueryBuilder.  see my answer for what should work.

Comment: @the_nuts then adds the `userProfile` join statement to the query builder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Explicitly create the join in your QueryBuilder, and select both the user and allowed users.

**UPDATE**

You must also join and select your user profile and user settings **OneToOne** relations because Doctrine automatically retrieves **OneToOne** relations any time you fetch the User entity.

The [Doctrine documentation talks about](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#why-is-an-extra-sql-query-executed-every-time-i-fetch-an-entity-with-a-one-to-one-relation) why it has to perform an extra query when fetching the inverse side of a one-to-one relation.

```
->add('allowedUsers', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u, au, up, us')
            ->join('u.allowedUsers', 'au')
            ->join('u.userProfile', 'up')
            ->join('u.userSettings', 'us')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC')
        ;
    },
    'label' => 'Allowed users',
    'required' => false,
    'multiple' => true
])
```

Comment: You're a genius :) Btw it worked after removing the `->join('u.allowedUsers', 'au')` line, because that relation doesn't exist (the allowed users are related to the offer, not to the user)

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah the OneToOne relation thing tripped me up for a long time, and in one extreme case I changed the ORM schema to think it's a OneToMany, but through code still treated it like a OneToOne.  Either way joins are your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have queries to your "entity" that don't need to fetch `allowedUsers` the simplest way would be to explicitly define fetch mode as `EAGER` in the field's annotations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *  name="offer_allowedusers",
 *  joinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *  },
 *  inverseJoinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *  }
 * )
 */
private $allowedUsers;
```

Comment: Done, but nothing changed